# Encoding long numbers into characters for higher base numbering system

Tags: javascript, encoding, hex, file-transfer, radix

I have a huge array that's made up of long lists of integers, such as `[196879, 37893, 137892]`. This array is 4.5 million integers long, and takes up 21MB, which is a lot to transfer via JSON to my webpage.

My question is: is there a way to encode these integers into alphanumeric values to reduce filesize? I'm thinking something similar to hexadecimal, where `a=10, b=11, c=12...`, but with a higher radix. If we have 0-9, a-z, and A-Z, we could theoretically build a base-62 numbering system that looks like this: `9Eo, bZ3, xQ, 9p1, wNd`. Does such a file format exist, or is there a JavaScript tool that could encode and then decode an array in such a manner?

Comment: `a base-62 numbering system` - have you heard of base64 - although, you wouldn't use traditional base64 techniques for this

Comment: these integers ... what is the range of values?

Comment: @JaromandaX I have them limited from -100,000 to 100,000

Comment: even base64 wont help that much - quick calculation would save less than 1MB transfer

Answer (score 4):

I believe you could create an array of the integers, convert that to binary, then upload that blob. Each integer will take 4 bytes.

```
var count = 14.5 * 1000000;
var integers = new Int32Array(count);
var min = -100000;
var max = 100000;

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    integers[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

var blob = new Blob([integers]);

var data = new FormData();
data.append('data', blob);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/some_page',
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
}).done(function(data) {
   // TODO
});
```

Comment: Hmm... this might work! When I post the data, I could write a PHP script to store it. What file format do I save it to, a .bin file?

Comment: If you just save it as is, the format would just be binary (raw bytes, each set of 4 bytes just happen to be one of your integers). You can use whatever file extension you like; .bin or .dat are good choices for something so generic, or .tmp if its a temp file.  You could post process the raw data into a more useful format once its uploaded - e.g. re-write it in CSV format, or JSON, etc, or insert them into a DB, etc